# How to ping / traceroute an AWS ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-elb

Amazon's load balancers have a network security policy which swallows ICMP packets for both `ping` and `traceroute`.  It is listed as security group `amazon-elb/amazon-elb-sg`.  Personally I find these tools pretty helpful in diagnosing problems, so I'd like to be able to use them on my service.  I'd rather the load balancer either responds to these requests or forwards them.

Is there any way to change the security group settings on an ELB?  Or any other way to verify IP connectivity to the ELB?

**Update**

To be clear, I see no way in the AWS console to either set the SG on a newly created ELB, nor to change the SG on an existing ELB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [is possible in a VPC](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=376782#jive-message-294990), but not in stock EC2.

Comment: @vy32 This answer is from 2013, when it was entirely accurate.

Comment: This answer is no longer accurate. You need to go into the Security Groups and allow incoming ICMP traffic.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this works for Classic Load Balancers and Application Load Balancers. Go into your security group settings and permit incoming ICMP traffic on the one that is assigned to your ELB. Security groups work the same whether they're assigned to an ELB or EC2 instance.

I just tested and confirmed:

```
[jjbegin@bane ~]$ ping elb01-2026631704.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com 
PING elb01-2026631704.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com (107.23.23.138) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ec2-107-23-23-138.compute-1.amazonaws.com (107.23.23.138): icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=36.2 ms
64 bytes from ec2-107-23-23-138.compute-1.amazonaws.com (107.23.23.138): icmp_seq=2 ttl=51 time=35.9 ms
^C
--- elb01-2026631704.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1473ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 35.985/36.121/36.258/0.233 ms
[jjbegin@bane ~]$
```

NOTE: This does not work for Network Load Balancers (NLB). They do not have security groups and all ICMP Packets except for Type 3 (Destination Unreachable) are considered "Unintended traffic" and are not forwarded to any targets. [Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-listeners.html)

Comment: My ELB has a security group which I do not own.  It is owned by "amazon-elb" and I see neither an option to change the security group nor an option to set the security group when I create a new ELB.

Comment: You must be using Elastic Beanstalk.  In that case, there is no way to adjust the security group settings on the ELB's security groups.  And you can't add/remove a security group unless you're using a VPC.  What are you're trying to do?  Monitor uptime?

Comment: I'm not using beanstalk.  I'm trying to figure out what's wrong when things go wrong.

Comment: You don't see something like this? http://i.imgur.com/fFdqvEA.png

Comment: I do not.  http://i.imgur.com/dQDy9jr.png